# Formatting a value from a Currency

Tags: java

I'm familiar with:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
System.out.println(fmt.format(120.00));
```

as a method, only I have a `java.util.Currency`, not a locale. There seems to be no way to get the locale from the `Currency` only the other way around.

I've done this for now:

```
public String format(Currency currency, long value) {
    int defaultFractionDigits = currency.getDefaultFractionDigits();
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();       
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(defaultFractionDigits);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(defaultFractionDigits);
    double divider = Math.pow(10, defaultFractionDigits);
    return String.format("%s %s", currency.getSymbol(Locale.getDefault()), format.format(value/divider));
}
```

So I'm wondering if there's a clearner way?

Note `value` is defined in the smallest part of the currency, e.g. a cent or a penny. But that's not important for purpose of question, would take answer that formatted a floating value.

Comment: to test methods in AbstractFormatterFactory/InternationalFormatter

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at [Joda Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/).

Comment: Nice idea, actually solves a lot of my issues. I'm using Joda time already, but I didn't know of this.